# Python, a sum() issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to compute the total sum of all these `ord`s so I have decided to use the `sum()` built in function.

What happens though it outputs the sum total x4 when I run the script. Anyone know why?

```
T = ord('a'), ord('b'), ord('c'), ord('d')

for c in T:
    c = sum(T)
    print(c)
```

edit:

```
T = "hi chris"

total = 0
for c in T:
    total += ord(c)
    print(total)
```

This seems to be working but its calculation each one individually, i want 1 sum and the total, not each characters total individually...

Comment: OK, I'll ask the obvious(?) question: What is the point of summing the ord() of each of a bunch of characters? It seems to be up there with summing the latitudes or longitudes of some cities or the years of birth of some prominent people ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to put the `sum` in a loop. It automatically works on the whole list.

```
total = sum(T)
```

Alternatively, don't use `sum`:

```
total = 0
for c in T:
    total += c
```

in which case you can use a loop.

For a bit more info, see the [built-in functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) docs.

Comment: or even `sum([ord(_) for _ in "abcd"])`

Comment: @Kimvais: You do not need to create lists, just use `sum(ord(i) for i in "abcd")` instead. You can also use a map as in `sum(map(ord, "abcd"))`.

Comment: Also, I'd like to note using the underscore is really unclear and unpythonic - in other languages (like prolog) ``_`` is often used to throw away an argument you don't care about, so this usage looks really weird. Use a name like ``character`` that tells you what the variable is.

Comment: Yeah i am new to python and i am reading learning python so i have come across exercises, and i got stuck that's all... problem is once i convert the ords() into a ASCII integer i then need to compute the total...

Comment: @user1265535 Either of the two code snippets in my answer compute the total. Just add `print(total)` to the end of either one and you'll see.

Comment: @Lattyware: I agree with part about `_` (underscore). This should be used for throw away variables, not the ones you will use in the loop.

Comment: I have also seen `_` used (and use it myself) for i18n extensively, as the gettext function: `_('foo')`. Django in particular has this as a convention: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation. Also Python: http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop is incorrect. You are re-calculating the sum of `T` with each loop. Instead of doing this:

```
for c in T:
    c = sum(T)
    print(c)
```

do this:

```
print(sum(T))
```

or this:

```
s = 0
for c in T:
    s += c
print(s)
```